# How to invoke a REST Proxy service running on the ESB from a BPEL process on the BPS

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have setup BPS and have created a few BPEL processes which i can use to invoke services on the Application Server. I have created a REST proxy service on the ESB which uses an endpoint to a Labview server. In Labview i have a very basic REST service which generates a random value every second. I can access the REST service as follows `http://localhost:8000/Maths/random`. This generates the follwing output with a random value

```
RValue:19.000000
```

I have had success in accessing this service through the Gadget server and displaying the value as a graph using the WSO2 graphics framework.

But I am having problems when I try to invoke the same proxy service from a BPEL process. I have generated a wsdl file for the proxy service from the ESB. This wsdl file is used for the port connections etc. It only has one operation the "mediate" operation with no parameters or elements. I have followed a few of the tutorials for the BPS server to invoke the service but i have had no success so far. 
Can anyone show me how this can be done or point me to a similar tutorial?
Many thanks.

U Raza
 below is the BPS error i get

> [2012-03-15 18:22:33,265]  INFO - BpelServerImpl - Registered process {http://areasearvice.bpel.bps}AreaService-14.
>   [2012-03-15 18:22:42,282]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil - 'admin' logged in at [2012-03-15 18:22:42,0282] from IP address 143.53.207.235
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,041] ERROR - BpelObjectFactory$BOMSAXErrorHandler - null:file:///D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/RestfulProxy.bpel:88:56:cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xml:space' is not allowed to appear in element 'bpel:literal'.
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,043]  WARN - BpelObjectFactory - Validation errors during parsing, continuing due to -Dorg.apache.ode.compiler.failOnValidationErrors=false switch
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,046]  INFO - BpelC - info: [CompilingProcess] Compiling BPEL process.
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,116]  INFO - WSDLRegistry - WSDL at file:/D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/GetLVRandomProxy.wsdl is a duplicate import, your documents should all be in different namespaces (its's not nice but will still work).
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,116]  INFO - WSDLRegistry - WSDL at file:/D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/GetLVRandomProxy.wsdl is already imported, this denotes a circular reference.
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,134] ERROR - BpelC - file:/D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/RestfulProxy.bpel:72: error: [CopyToMessageFromNonMessage] Copy to message variable RestProxyPLRequest requires a message for the r-value.
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,139] ERROR - BpelC - file:/D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/RestfulProxy.bpel:95: error: [CopyFromMessageToNonMessage] Copy from message variable RestProxyPLResponse requires a message for the l-value.
>   [2012-03-15 18:23:09,143] ERROR - BPELUploadExecutor - BPEL Process Compilation Failure.
>   org.apache.ode.bpel.compiler.api.CompilationException: error: [CompilationErrors] Compilation completed with 2 error(s):
>       file:/D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/RestfulProxy.bpel:72: error: [CopyToMessageFromNonMessage] Copy to message variable RestProxyPLRequest requires a message for the r-value.
>       file:/D:/ESB/WSO2/wso2bps-2.1.0/tmp/work/bpelTemp/1.33183578879275E12/BPELREST/RestfulProxy.bpel:95: error: [CopyFromMessageToNonMessage] Copy from message variable RestProxyPLResponse requires a message for the l-value.
>       at org.apache.ode.bpel.compiler.BpelCompiler.compile(BpelCompiler.java:815)
>       at org.apache.ode.bpel.compiler.BpelC.compile(BpelC.java:278)
>       at org.apache.ode.bpel.compiler.BpelC.compile(BpelC.java:364)
>       at org.apache.ode.store.DeploymentUnitDir$5.run(DeploymentUnitDir.java:213)
>       at org.apache.ode.utils.InternPool.runBlock(InternPool.java:57)
>       at org.apache.ode.store.DeploymentUnitDir.compile(DeploymentUnitDir.java:210)
>       at org.apache.ode.store.DeploymentUnitDir.compile(DeploymentUnitDir.java:169)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.ui.fileupload.BPELUploadExecutor.validateBPELPackage(BPELUploadExecutor.java:262)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.ui.fileupload.BPELUploadExecutor.execute(BPELUploadExecutor.java:101)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.AbstractFileUploadExecutor.executeGeneric(AbstractFileUploadExecutor.java:105)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager$CarbonXmlFileUploadExecHandler.execute(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:392)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager$FileUploadExecutionHandlerManager.startExec(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:276)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.fileupload.FileUploadExecutorManager.execute(FileUploadExecutorManager.java:125)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.ui.transports.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:57)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.service(BridgeServlet.java:155)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.server.TomcatServer$1.invoke(TomcatServer.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:396)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:356)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and here I have provided a BPEL sample to invoke the following proxy service. Please find the sample artifacts from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/denis/bpel-rest-invocation-sample/).
Note - You have to get a api key from [goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/api) and replace with `MyKeyHere`.

```
<proxy name="GetProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2"/>
                <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/4776766.xml?key=MyKeyHere" scope="axis2"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://www.goodreads.com/author/list"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ESB proxy configuration that worked for me for a GET request.

```
<proxy name="GetProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2"/>
                <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/4776766.xml?key=MyKeyHere" scope="axis2"/>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://www.goodreads.com/author/list"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

This is for a POST request

```
<proxy name="TestProxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/emal/xml_api"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

BTW did you mean to say that you successfully accessed that proxy service via Gadget Server, but not via BPS? Can you post the ESB proxy configuration and the error logs you got from BPS?

Comment: Hi Keheliya Thanks for reply, I have setup a proxy as you have done and i can invoke it directly from the firefox browser and i get the expected output. In order to invoke it from a BPEL process a wsdl file is needed for the above proxies. What did the wsdl file look like which you used in BPS ? I am going to genereate one from the ESB and try to use that.

Comment: <proxy name="GetLVRandomProxy" transports="https,http" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>     is the proxy configuration used
         <log level="full" />
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" />
         <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/random" scope="axis2" />
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8000/Maths/" />
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>

Comment: Above is the proxy configuration i used and i can invoke that through a web browser. I want to invoke it from a BPEL process. How can i do this. I will try to use the wsdl file from ESB and create a simple process to invoke this service. anyway many thanks for your reply.  Umar