# Invoking a REST service from WSO2 BPEL workflow

Tags: rest, wso2, bpel

Is it possible to invoke a REST service directly from WSO2 BPEL workflow by defining a partner link? If yes, are there any resources available online on how to do this?

Thanks!
SR

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is

[How to invoke a REST Proxy service running on the ESB from a BPEL process on the BPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707851/how-to-invoke-a-rest-proxy-service-running-on-the-esb-from-a-bpel-process-on-the)

Hope the following resource will be helpful,

http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2012/03/restful-api-access-via-business.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be satisfied using WSDL 1.1 Extensions for REST with Apache ODE.Following blog post describes how to use BPEL process to call rest service.
http://waruapz.blogspot.com/2014/02/rest-service-with-ode-process.html